# How do I securely handle an array from $_POST?

Tags: php, security, user-input

My PHP Script is receiving an array via $_POST. The array has (or is expected to have) the following format:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
'Datum' => 
array (
  0 => '2016-11-29',
  1 => '2016-11-29',
  2 => '2016-11-29',
),
'VK' => 
array (
  0 => '18 Worker',
  1 => '1 Other Worker',
  2 => '11 One more worker',
),
'Dienstbeginn' => 
array (
  0 => '08:00',
  1 => '08:00',
  2 => '08:30',
),
'Dienstende' => 
array (
 0 => '14:00',
  1 => '16:30',
  2 => '16:00',
),
'Mittagsbeginn' => 
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '11:30',
  2 => '12:00',
),
'Mittagsende' => 
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '12:00',
  2 => '12:30',
),
'Kommentar' => 
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '',
  2 => '',
    ),
  ),
)
```

I have a function that writes the user data into my own variable and converts blank input into NULL-Values for the database to store.

```
foreach ($_POST['Dienstplan'] as $plan => $inhalt_tag) {
    foreach ($inhalt_tag as $column => $lines) {
        foreach ($lines as $linenumber => $line) {
            if ($line === '') {
                //Empty fields should be inserted as null values inside the database.
                //TODO: Should we make an exeption for Comments?
                $line = 'null';
            }
            //TODO: Is it a security issue, that we use $column and $linenumber directly? Do we have to sanitize those?
            $Dienstplan[$plan][$column][$linenumber] = sanitize_user_input($line);
        }
    }
}


function sanitize_user_input($data) {
  $clean_data = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($data)));
  return $clean_data;
}
```

How secure is this approach? Can I trust $plan, $column and $linenumber to be save in this context? Where is the first point, which an attacker could use to break things?

Comment: secure from what? [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)? its too broad

Comment: as you dont do anything with the variables, its 100% secure

Comment: The values are stored in a MySQL Database. The stored values are later on presented to the user via HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How secure is this approach? Can I trust $plan, $column and $linenumber to be save in this context?

No. You're using the wrong tool for the job, at multiple layers.

1. If you're trying to protect against SQL injection, [use prepared statements](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) instead of escaping input.
2. If you're trying to protect against cross-site scripting, [escape on output](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know), never on input.

If you want to validate structured input (i.e. for type safety, and also to enforce input whitelists), check out [Ionizer](https://github.com/paragonie/ionizer).